# X-Drupal-Cache header not always appearing on page

Tags: caching

I have a site which uses Drupal core anonymous caching.  However, I have noticed a very strange behavior. Sometimes I will load the home page and in the response headers will be the 'X-Drupal-Cache' header.  But if I reload the page again, the 'X-Drupal-Cache' header disappears.  I cannot understand how this could happen.

What might be the cause?

The response headers also containL `Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0`, which I understand will force the browser not to use a cached version of the page.

Strange thing is that if I access the same page using curl (e.g. `curl -I http://example.com/`), the X-Drupal-Cache header appears each and every time.

Comment: Are you sure the response is coming from the server? Is your browser returning a cached page?

Comment: Is there an easy way of checking if the page was served from the browser cache?

Comment: Depending on your browser, your networks tools should indicate where the response comes from. An alternative might be to use cURL: `curl -I http://example.com/`

Comment: @ShawnConn I tried using curl and updated my original question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is the result of having a browser cache. After the first request, your browser caches the document and keeps track of its  signature through the `Etag`/`Last-Modified` headers.

Upon subsequent requests, the browser makes a request to the server with the `If-None-Match`/ `If-Modified-Since` headers. If the document hasn't changed, the server returns a HTTP `304 Not Modified` which tells the browser it's okay to serve its cached version of the page.

Because cURL doesn't have a caching mechanism, `X-Drupal-Cache` always appears; it needs to go directly to Drupal each time for the document.